# How to close the non-modal dialog box by clicking outside in function using jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

here i define a function for calling various dialog boxes, but i am not able to close it by clicking outside .please help me.

Thanks

javascript

```
/*function for dialog box */

function dialogBox(dialoge,opener){
if(dialoge.length>0 && opener.length>0){
  dialoge.dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 300,  //width
    height: "auto",

    buttons: {
      Close: function() {
        dialoge.dialog( "close" );
      }
  }
  });
 $("body").on("click",".ui-widget-overlay",function() {
 dialoge.dialog( "close" );   /*this works for modal */
 });
  opener.click(function() {
    dialoge.dialog("open");
    return false;
  });    
 }
 }
```

function calling

```
 var desc_add = $(".dialog");
 var desc_open = $(".opener");
 if(desc_add && desc_open){
desc_open.change(function(){
  dialogBox(desc_add, desc_open);
  });
 dialogBox(desc_add, desc_open);
 }
```

ruby

```
<%= image_tag("/assets/help.png", :alt => "info", class: "opener") %>
<div id="dialog" title="HELP">for the addess</div>
```

Comment: Hi! can you provide us a full working example? Thanks!

Comment: this is workin'

Comment: I mean a full working example... something that I can copy and paste to simulate here. Also your javascript has a }) extra...

Comment: u can copy this js and put in ready function, it will work

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples here that might suit your case:

[How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element?rq=1)

don't forget to fix your javascript, it has an extra })